# Get ouput value of AT command in PHP via fopen

Tags: php, at-command

I manage how to send sms using gsm in php by this code:

```
exec("MODE COM3: BAUD=115200 PARITY=N DATA=8 STOP=1", $output, $retval);

$fp = fopen("COM3","r+");
if(!$fp){
   echo "Error Com Port";
}



fwrite($fp,"AT+CMGF=1\n\r");



fwrite($fp, "AT+CMGS=\"09123456789\"\r");
fwrite($fp, "Hello World".chr(26));


var_dump(fread($fp, 1));

fclose($fp);
```

Now i want to achieve when i type this

```
fwrite($fp,"AT+CMGF=1\n\r");
```

it will echo the status of AT like 'OK'

Thanks.